# Java assignment operator

Tags: java, variable-assignment, equality, convention

The following blockquote is taken from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html

> Do not use the assignment operator in a place where it can be easily confused with the equality operator. Example:
>
> ```
> if (c++ = d++) {        // AVOID! (Java disallows)
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> should be written as
>
> ```
> if ((c++ = d++) != 0) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

I am confused by the line

```
if ((c++ = d++) != 0) {
```

Any clarification on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very beginning of the page I can see -

> This page is not being actively maintained. Links within the documentation may not work and the information itself may no longer be valid. The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999

```
    if ((c++ = d++) != 0) {
        //logic
    }
```

Syntax is not even valid (Using Java6). It gives me

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

You need to assign c++ to some variable.

Comment: It's not valid in java 8 either.  Same error.  But take the `++` off of the `c` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast with other languages like C, Java's scalar primitives (integers, etc.) cannot be used as booleans.  In other words, `0` is in no sense either `true` or `false`.  Only whether something *is equal to* `0` can be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`(c++ = d++)` is an integer expression, not a boolean expression. It evaluates to whatever integer `c` got assigned to in the `c++ = d++` assignment.  Hence `if (c++ = d++) {` is a non starter in java.

So the comparison with 0 is what it takes to convert the integer expression to boolean.

And I think it goes without saying. Code written as follows:

```
if ((c++ = d++) != 0) {
```

is just bad coding.  First, the the inner assignment within a comparison.  Then the postfix operators within it. Both contribute to a block of code that is  difficult to read, easy opportunities for bugs, difficult to maintain etc...  Better written as follows:

```
c = d;
c++;
d++;
if (c == d) {
```

But you already knew that. :)

Answer (score 0):

They're just trying to say that the compiler requires the condition of an `if` statement to evaluate to a `boolean` value.  If you know what you're doing, and decide to put actual code with side effects as the condition, you're required to make the expression evaluate to a value of type `boolean`.

Whereas the anti-pattern code in the example would work out in a programming language like C where `boolean` values are actually integers (where zero is `false`, and non-zero is `true`), the proper way to do this in Java is to actually compare the result to 0.